# Play Framework: case-insensitive matching in play.libs.XPath

Tags: xpath, playframework, case-insensitive

The Play Framework provides a great XPath object for processing XML documents. For example, to select `foobar` nodes from an xml document you could use

```
List<Node> nodes = XPath.selectNodes(".//foobar", xmlDocument);
```

However, this is case sensitive (as expected), so if you were to run the same query on an xml document that had the elements named `fooBar` instead, then no nodes would be found.

Through my google searches I found that "case-insensitive" searching can be achieved by making the node name lower case:

```
.//[lower-case(@foobar)]
```

Does anyone know how I would apply that to work with the Play Framework's [XPath lib](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.4/play%2Flibs%2FXPath.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what Play, specifically, supports, but you have a couple options. First, if Play supports XPath 2.0, then use `lower-case`:

```
//*[lower-case(local-name())='foo']
```

If `lower-case` is not supported, then use the XPath 1.0 `translate` function to imitate it:

```
//*[translate(local-name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                            'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='foo']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. After revisiting this problem I realised this is completely the correct answer and I apologise for taking so long to accept it. And just to add a bit of relative information, XPath 2.0 is supported by the Play Framework.